# Ruby console/terminal display an image to the best possible way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ascii

This is just for the sake of curiosity.

If I have a jpeg file or gif or something. Is it possible to display it
(in color if possible) onto the terminal/rails console (you know.. like those ASCII
8 bit style images)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/612099#) might be what you are looking for.

[image: Example]